# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia does not resolve

Tags: firefox, media, policy, getusermedia, autoplay

I found out, that the getUserMedia Promise in Firefox only resolves, if the Tab is active or by clicking on the Tab Instance: (Firefox, 81.0)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true}).then(() => console.log("done"))
```

Otherwise, the Promise never resolves or rejects. It looks for me like a bug.

I have seen that behaviour in Firefox only. Safari and Chrome are working fine. I also have played around the media Settings in about:config, but nothing helped

In my tests, I have accepted Audio Permission permanently.

Thx

(edit): **Additional Information:**
Firefox has the setting in about:config **media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground**. But this setting doesn't change the behaviour. Maybe it should?

(edit 2020-12-10: related Forum Post on Mozo;;a Forum: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1307318)

**(Solved)**

The strict Media policy can be bypassed by going to

```
about:prererences -> Security -> Autoplay
```

This gives the possibility to disable Autoplay blocking, or whitelisting Websites with autoplay enabled, and makes it possible to play Media for Background Tabs/Windows.

**Edit (2020-12-01)**

After a little testing and investigation, I found out that playing Audio in non-focused Firefox Tabs/Window is possible with Autoplay. But unfortunately, it is still not possible to bypass the strict policy when it comes to WebRTC/SIP. The Promise stil doesn't resolve.

Comment: Autoplay configuration controls playback from `<audio>` or `<video>` tags for what it's worth.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I have autoplay active for the Audio Node I am using. I am pretty sure the behaviour of Firefox is not as it supposed to . It is not officially confirmed yet, and I would like to have some confirmation from the Community

Comment: You can file a Firefox defect report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/  If you present a complete example so the team can reproduce the problem, they'll take it seriously.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1195654
It looks like the Firefox behaviour is not a bug, but a security Feature.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the first comment correctly. You can set the autoplay attribute on a <audio> or <video> Tag. The strict Media policy can only be bypassed by going to 

    about:prererences -> Security -> Autoplay

This gives the possibility to disable Autoplay blocking, or whitelisting Websites with autoplay enabled.